# how to add a dynamic bootstrap class with vue.js?

Tags: javascript, object

I am learning vue.js. I would like to add dynamic class values to my template. However when I try to add a bootstrap 4 class appears the following error:

```
v-bind' directives require an attribute value
```

I put the value `true` to the class `img-fluid` but I didn't solve the problem.
My template is the following:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <img src="images/retro.jpg" v-bind:class="{card:true, invisible:pc_left_invisible}" id="pc_left" v-bind:rel="pc_left_rel">
            <img src="images/retro.jpg" v-bind:class="{card:true, invisible:pc_center_invisible}" id="pc_center" v-bind:rel="pc_center_rel">
            <img src="images/retro.jpg" v-bind:class="{card:true, invisible:pc_right_invisible}" id="pc_right" v-bind:rel="pc_right_rel">
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3 d-flex justify-content-start">
                <img src="images/retro.jpg" v-bind:class="{card:true, invisible:pack_cards_invisible}" id="pack_cards" rel="0">
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 d-flex justify-content-center">
                <img v-bind:src="pc_game_src" v-bind:class="{card:true, invisible:pc_game_invisible, img-fluid: true}" id="pc_game" v-bind:rel="pc_game_rel"> <!--here the error-->
                <img v-bind:src="player_game_src" v-bind:class="{card:true, invisible:player_game_invisible}" id="player_game" v-bind:rel="player_game_rel">
            </div>
            <div class="col-3 d-flex justify-content-end">
                <img v-bind:src="game_briscola_src"  v-bind:class="{card:true, invisible:game_briscola_invisible}" id="game_briscola" v-bind:rel="game_briscola_rel">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <img @click="play($event)" v-bind:src="player_left_src" v-bind:class="{card:true, invisible:player_left_invisible}" id="player_left" v-bind:rel="player_left_rel">
            <img @click="play($event)" v-bind:src="player_center_src" v-bind:class="{card:true, invisible:player_center_invisible}" id="player_center" v-bind:rel="player_center_rel">
            <img @click="play($event)" v-bind:src="player_right_src" v-bind:class="{card:true, invisible:player_right_invisible}" id="player_right" v-bind:rel="player_right_rel">
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

This is the styles section:

```
<style scoped>
.card {
    border-radius: 10%;
    height: 30vh;
    width: 20vh;
}
</style>
```

So the class that creates problems is the bootstrap class `img-fluid`. Can help?

Comment: `obj.img-fluid` is not valid syntax, as it contains a hyphen.  `obj['img-fluid']` is. Your class needs to be a valid key property in the object you're passing to `:class`.

Comment: In other words, apart from having to satisfy conditions for valid CSS class naming, they also need to satisfy conditions for [Property Accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors), because they're treated as object keys when passed as object. So your question has nothing to do with either Bootstrap or Vue. It's a vanilla JavaScript question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a plain javascript issue, as in javascript we can not have object's key with a hyphen `-` like:

```js
const obj = { img-fluid: true }
console.log( obj )
//==> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '-'
```

You can using a key with a hyphen gives a syntax error. We can easily fix this issue by wrapping the key in quotes like:

```js
const obj = { 'img-fluid': true }
console.log( obj )
```

So, in vuejs also you can fix this like:

```
v-bind:class="{card:true, invisible:pc_game_invisible, 'img-fluid': true}"
```